# How do I easily retrieve the total depth of a tree in ancestry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

Ancestry has many wonderful scopes and methods, including `node.depth` (which returns a depth level - i.e. 0 for root nodes, 1 for the child, etc.).

It also has some scopes that allow you to traverse a tree by depth, e.g. `node.subtree(:to_depth => 2)`.

But I don't see anything that indicates how to calculate/retrieve the total depth of the entire tree - from the root to the last node.

The only thing I can think of is to create a `total_depth_cache` column on my model, that as a new child is added, it increments that. But then I have to write the logic to manage that (i.e. whenever all children are deleted, it decrements - if there is just 1 level, but if a child with say 3 levels of children gets deleted, the depth would then have to be updated accordingly). That can get pretty complicated very quickly.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to get the count of children?  `node.descendant_ids.count` ?

Comment: Nah...that doesn't work...because it includes siblings. i.e. if `node A` has 2 children, and each child has 1 child. `node.descendant_ids.count` will return 4, whereas the total depth should be 3 (i.e. root -> child -> grandchild) if that makes sense.

Comment: A bit of a stinker. You could use a `total_depth_cache` but you'd have to recalculate it on after_create and after_destroy for the parent by iterating through all children, then the parent's parent, etc. then stop when you see no change since the parents won't change either.  If it's a volatile tree and you don't need total_depth often, may be better iterating through all children to calculate total_depth on an 'as needed' basis.  You can't be sure a parent's cache value needs to change without examining all other child branches.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn That's kinda what I was thinking....but that way kinda sucks. I may just have to do it that way. I wish there was a `max_depth` or a `last_depth` method or something. That would make this much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a `last_depth` recursive method you can add to the model...

```
class Node
  def last_depth
    if child_ids.empty?
      return depth
    else
      return children.map{|c| c.last_depth}.max
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT: to clarify, the method will return the current depth of a node if it has no children, otherwise it will call itself on all the children of the current node and return the largest result.  The net result will be the largest "depth" value in the tree.

Comment: This feels like it may give a "stack level too deep" error? It certainly looks interesting.

Comment: You get a "stack level too deep" in a recursion if you fail to provide a base case (the case where the method isn't called).  In this example when there are no `child_ids` (no children) it doesn't call, it just returns the current depth, so that's the base case, and you're certain to reach the base case because (eventually) you'll, while calling children, reach nodes that don't have children.

The actual stack level should never be greater than the last_depth count, so I don't think stack overflow is likely.

Comment: I think that this recursive method ends up making two queries for each recursion - one for `child_ids` and another for `children`, right? I find @nahankid's solution a little better in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of retrieving the depth of a tree in ancestry. One of the most readable one is:

```
node.subtree.select(&:is_childless?).map(&:depth).max
```

This finds max depth of all leaf nodes.

Comment: Could you please provide some details about why this solves the OP's problem?

Comment: This is a cleaner solution than the accepted answer. Using `is_childless?` allows the ancestry gem to yield the set of leaf nodes, which are all we care about here.